# I can't run Molden from my cygwin window

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I'm using cygwin, xming and molden on my laptop running Windows 7.
When I'm on my lab computer running Linux (I think it's the Mandriva one) I'm able to call Molden via the terminal just by stating 'molden "nameofthefile"', but on my laptop I have this message instead :
"Molden: cannot connect to X server"

I think I missed something after installing molden, but I don't know what.

Comment: Have you started the X server?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell Molden where to find the X server, by setting the DISPLAY variable, for example:

```
DISPLAY=:0 molden "nameofthefile"
```

(You don't usually need to do that on Linux, because Linux terminals are themselves X clients, so the DISPLAY variable is already set. That isn't the case with the Cygwin terminal.)

Comment: I tried that:
 DISPLAY=:0 molden geo.xyz
Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Molden: cannot connect to X server :0

Any new advice ? (or what have I done wrong ? :p )

Comment: Nifle's question seems pertinent then: have you started the X server, i.e. Xming?

Comment: Yes I have. There is not more to do than just executing it ?

Comment: No, that should do it. Do you see Xming's icon in the tray? It works for me, at least with standard X clients such as `xterm`. You might want to try that in case it's an issue specific to `molden` (which I know nothing about). A firewall blocking the connection is the only other possibility I can think of.

Comment: Yes, I have Xming's miniature icon. I tried authorizing Xming and Cygwin in the firewall options, even tried with firewall down, still "Molden: cannot connect to X server".
Maybe I'll try Xterm, and I'm thinking about installing a Linux OS ^^